# Mobile nav not properly positioning on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I've created a menu that is styled as a dropdown on small screens, and shows up inline at the top of the browser on larger screens. It works perfectly, except for when you resize your browser down.

When you scale your browser from large screen to small, the dropdown nav shows up momentarily before sliding up to the top of the screen. There's a transition added to the `.header .nav` so that it enters and exits gracefully.

Any suggestions are welcome, especially those that don't require javascript (I've tried to keep this light on javascript). I'd also like to keep the transition if I can, since the client has already seen it.

```js
var navTop = document.querySelector('#nav');
var menuBtn = document.querySelector('#js-nav-btn');

if (navTop) {
  document.querySelector('#js-nav-btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (navTop.getAttribute('data-state') == 'expanded') {
      navTop.setAttribute('data-state', 'collapsed');
    } else {
      navTop.setAttribute('data-state', 'expanded');
    }
  });
} else {};
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  height: 40em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
/* header */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f3f4f7;
  z-index: 100;
}
.header-bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f3f4f7;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 93;
}
.header .logo {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 101;
  position: relative;
}
.header .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 92;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: top 0.5s ease;
  transition: top 0.5s ease;
}
.header .nav ul {
  position: relative;
}
.header .nav li {
  line-height: 6;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
.header .main-nav a {
  display: block;
}
/* nav states. Show and hide */

.nav[data-state="collapsed"] {
  top: -50em;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -5;
}
.nav[data-state="expanded"] {
  top: 56px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 30;
}
.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 2em;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
.menu-btn-div {
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #9bacb5;
}
.menu-btn .menu-btn-top {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.menu-btn .menu-btn-mid {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.menu-btn .menu-btn-bot {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 40em) {
  .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav,
  .nav[data-state="collapsed"],
  .nav[data-state="expanded"] {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 94;
  }
  .header .nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header .main-nav {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    right: 5em;
  }
  .header .main-nav li {
    padding-left: 0.75em;
  }
  .header .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="header">
  <div class="header-bg"></div>
  <!--header-bg is there so you can't see the mobile nav overtop of the header bar when it expands-->

  <div class="logo">
  </div>

  <nav id="nav" class="nav" data-state="collapsed">
    <div class="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav top-nav">
        <li class=""><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <a class="menu-btn" id="js-nav-btn" href="#">
    <!--hamburger menu icon-->
    <div class="menu-btn-div menu-btn-top"></div>
    <div class="menu-btn-div menu-btn-mid"></div>
    <div class="menu-btn-div menu-btn-bot"></div>
  </a>

</header>

<div id="container">
  <!-- main page content goes here-->
</div>
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/meg/eek50292/7/ (scale the "results" tab up and then down to see the effect)

Comment: its due to the `transition: top 0.5s ease;` effect you have on the `.header .nav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to hide the menu automatically when the max-width is less than 40em:

```
@media all and (max-width: 40em){
    .nav[data-state="collapsed"]{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
        .nav[data-state="expanded"]{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

The fiddle is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/mfwbe34m/  - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I just realized that does remove the transition when the menu is closed... could be a starting point for you though

Comment: This does seem to work in the fiddle. For some reason though, it didn't work in the site I'm working on. I managed to fix the problem by making a second nav that only shows up on larger screens. It's not ideal, but the functionality that I need works now.

Comment: But since your fiddle worked, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!